# Many to one merging sql

Tags: sql, join, merge, set

I have three tables as below:

```
First Table           Second Table    Third Table 
Name   PIN            Id   City         City_id  
David  1948           1    Roma          3
Susan  1245           2    Berlin        2
Jack   1578           3    New York      3
Hans   1247                              2
Rose   8745                              1
```

I want to merge first and second table according to third table. Result will be: Person

```
Name  PIN  City
David 1948 New York
Susan 1245 Berlin
Jack  1578 New York
Hans  1247 Berlin
Rose  8745 Roma
```

Firsty I can merge second and third table and then merge the result table with first table but I want to solve this problem without a medium table. How can I handle this? How can I combine first table's rows in sequence with a specified row in second table according to third table?

Comment: You can't unless there's a column (or combination of columns) in each the first and third table that defines the order. And from what you've showed it doesn't seem like there are such columns.

Comment: I assume that your Third Table is listing the City_id associated with each Name in the First Table. This won't work unless you have a foreign key to associate the records of the first table with the third. Relational databases do not support _assuming_ record order, so you need to have another column in the third table with the ID of the records in the first. And you should add an ID column to the first table since you could easily have, for example, more than one `David` (I doubt I'm the David you are referring to.

Comment: don't worry about order you can simply think that third table shows city ids of first table in sequence.I can of course merge first and third table directly and then I can join the result table with second table using ids but I want to solve this problem without using a medium table.

Comment: You don't understand - there is no concept of "in sequence" in SQL. You can't depend on the order of Table 1 and Table 3 being the same. In SQL there MUST be something to bind the records together - not the order you _think_ they might appear within the tables.

Comment: Don't worry, but try to learn how relational databases work: They need unique identifiers for records. Think of it this way: The database is _not_ required to store your data in any particular order, so it might place your record `Jack` in a free location that is before where it stored `Susan`. If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause when you select the records, you have no guaranty that they will appear in their original order. There's no reason for SQL to support that since the rules require you to specify the order when you need it.

Comment: I am worried if there is not any method to say sql : Merge all rows of the table with a specified row defined in another table? I tried something like that did not work I knew it would not work but thought maybe there was a similar way:     select * from table1 left join (select city from table2) on (  secondtable.id=thirdtable.id)  It gave reference error

Comment: OK then I think the only way is merging 1. and 3. table and then left join the result with second table is it right? I actually need this for my sas code . Merging works well for sas like that: data result; merge table1 table3; then I can use sql like that:       select *from result left join (select city from table2) on(result.city_id=table2.id)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a fourth table, PersonCity, with PersonID and CityID to link together. Think of relational databases like a grid (spreadsheet, roads). If you're going North and the street you want to get on is parallel (think |^|   |^|) you're gonna need to use a different road that links the two. Currently, you have no such path.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the "spreadsheet" analogy doesn't fit because in a spreadsheet, the order of the rows is determined, but the OP is having trouble understanding that in a database, the order of records in a table is indeterminate.

Comment: Spreadsheet is an example of a grid, and having more than one sheet would require linking values in at least one column to correlate-  it's a classic example of how a relational database works. I understand that they are under the impression of record order being determinate, but the actual information that would help is understanding references, right? That's why I attempted to address it in that manner :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your tables are not adequate for the task, what you need is along the lines of:

```
Table_1                   Table_2          Table_3 
Id  Name   PIN            Id   City        Name_id City_id  
1   David  1948           1    Roma        1        3
2   Susan  1245           2    Berlin      2        2
3   Jack   1578           3    New York    3        3
4   Hans   1247                            4        2
5   Rose   8745                            5        1
```

Then you can do your query as follow:

```
   SELECT T1.Name, T1.PIN, T2.City
       FROM Table_1 T1 LEFT JOIN Table_3 T2 ON T1.Id = T3.Name_id
       LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON T3.City_id = T2.Id
       ORDER BY T1.Name
```

Or you could `ORDER BY` City, name

Comment: you meant? SELECT T1.Name, T1.PIN, T2.City
       FROM Table_1 T1 LEFT JOIN Table_3 T3 ON T1.Id = T3.Name_id
       LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON T3.City_id = T2.Id
       ORDER BY T1.Name

Comment: Sorry, yes, I edited my answer to fix the table number.

Comment: Unless a person (`table1`) can be related to more than one city (`table2`), the `city_id` can go directly in `table_1` and `table_3` can be dropped all together.

Comment: Sticky bit: That is true, but I would "assume" that the city table might have additional information added at some point which would justify the database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news.

The good news, Given the tables the way they were originally specified, in Oracle, this will give you something that looks like what you are asking:

```
---
--- Pay attention, This looks right but it is not!
---
select name,pin,city from
  ( select name,pin,rownum rn from first ) a,
  ( select city,id from second) b,
  ( select id,rownum rn from third  ) c
  where
  a.rn=c.rn AND
  b.id=c.id;

NAME                     PIN  CITY
-------------------- ---- --------------------
Rose                     8745 Roma
Susan                    1245 Berlin
Hans                     1247 Berlin
David                    1948 New York
Jack                     1578 New York
```

The bad news is this does not really work and is cheating.  You will get results but they may not be what you would expect and they won't necessarily be consistent.

The database orders records in its own order.  If you don't specify an `order by` clause, you get what they give you, which may not be what you want. This is cheating because Oracle does not *REALLY* support using rownum in this way because you can't bet on what you will get. This won't work in most other databases.

The only correct way is what @daShier gave, where you have to add something, say, ID, to allow connecting the rows in the order you want.